# Message app open in message composer only

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I'm trying to open Android Message app list in order to verify some incoming messages.
It only allows me to run`ConversationComposer`, while I don't need to compose a new message but only the messages list.
I have downloaded `APK Info` app, and tried several activities. All of them , beside the infamous `ConversationComposer` pop up an error.

This is my code:

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.SetCapability("device", "Android");
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy Note5");
        capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "6000");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
        capabilities.SetCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
        capabilities.SetCapability("noReset", true);
        capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.samsung.android.messaging");
        capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", "com.android.mms.ui.ConversationComposer");
```

I have tried `com.android.mms.ui.CoversationList` but getting `activity denied - no permission`

Comment: You can use `Appium Studio`, it will help you to find your expected `appActivity` by it's recording function.

Comment: @AI Imran Appium Studio wont be of any help outside Apppium studio environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android Version 7** should not throw any permission error while going to conversation composer

```
adb shell am start -n com.samsung.android.messaging/com.android.mms.ui.ConversationComposer
```

However,i am not sure,if you can  get directly to inbox messages

**Alternative**

There must be a **back buttton**, when the conversation composer opens

get the Locator of **Back button**  , **Click** it via code and you will be in message list.

Comment: it opens the conversation composer messages

Comment: Can't you verify the incoming message from here!!

Comment: no because this page is the conversation composer. meaning, this is the page where you are creating a new message, while I want to get into the messages list (the incoming messages page)

Comment: There must be a back button in this conversation composer..Get the locator for back button, click it and u will be in conversation list!!

Comment: yep..I did it already but wanted to get there directly and not as a workaround. write it as an answer and mention it's a workaround and I'll accept it..no one else wrote an answer to this post beside you anyway. cheers